# How to get latest timestamped result from time series in a join table

Tags: postgresql, join, foreign-key, psql

### I have 3 tables

```
node
----
id
ip

metric
---
id
key (str)
node_id (FK on node)


his_metric
----
id
metric_id (FK on metric)
value (float)
datetime (datetime)
```

### Question

How to write a query that will retrieve all `metrics` with their latest historic metric as a join value.

Example

```
===================================================================================
node_ip | metric_id | metric_key | last_hismetric_value | last_hismetric_datetime |
--------|-----------|------------|----------------------|-------------------------|
1.1.1.1 |     1     | uptime     | 24                   | 2020-04-29 19:53:10.00  |
--------|-----------|------------|----------------------|-------------------------|
1.1.1.1 |     2     | ping       | 188                  | 2020-04-29 19:53:10.00  |
--------|-----------|------------|----------------------|-------------------------|
1.1.1.1 |     3     | memory     | 512                  | 2020-04-29 19:53:10.00  |
--------|-----------|------------|----------------------|-------------------------|
2.2.2.2 |     4     | uptime     | 22                   | 2020-04-29 19:53:10.00  |
--------|-----------|------------|----------------------|-------------------------|
2.2.2.2 |     5     | ping       | 288                  | 2020-04-29 19:53:10.00  |
--------|-----------|------------|----------------------|-------------------------|
2.2.2.2 |     6     | memory     | 1024                 | 2020-04-29 19:53:10.00  |
===================================================================================
```

I was able to get close to my desired outcome except I cannot get the `his_metric.value` with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT metric.id, node.ip, metric.key, last_hismetric.datetime FROM metric 
LEFT JOIN (select his_metric.metric_id, max(his_metric.datetime) as datetime from his_metric group by his_metric.metric_id) last_hismetric ON (metric.id = last_hismetric.metric_id)
INNER JOIN node ON (node.id = metric.node_id)
ORDER BY metric.id DESC LIMIT 100
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Duplicate of [Get rows with most recent date for each different item](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190815/get-rows-with-most-recent-date-for-each-different-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
with cte as (
select metric_id, value, datetime, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY metric_id ORDER BY datetime desc) as rn
from his_metric
)

select n.ip, m.id, m.key, m_h.value, m_h.datetime
from metric as m
join node as n on m.node_id = n.id
join cte as m_h on m.id = m_h.metric_id and m_h.rn=1
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. It works! Cheers!