# How to retrieve rows with max value in one column for each combination of other two columns?

Tags: select, postgresql-11, distinct

I need to query an SQL database to find all records with max RATE for each combination of fields A and B. For example, consider the following table with 4 columns, A, B, RATE & VALUE:

```
A B RATE VALUE
= = ==== =====
a b 10   100
a b 2    110
a c 1    20
a c 3    55
a d 8    22
b c 3    10
```

I wish to get back one row from each distinct pair A & B with max RATE, getting these rows:

```
A B RATE VALUE
= = ==== =====
a b 10   100
a c 3    55
a d 8    22
b c 3    10
```

How can I formulate such a query in SQL?

Comment: Which rdms are you using, the differences are small but there

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: i'm using Postgres 11.5

Comment: Basically the same as [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190815/get-rows-with-most-recent-date-for-each-different-item) and many other similar questions, just replace the timestamp with your `value`.

Comment: @mustaccio yes it helped, thank you